# What happens in the DOM when the page is scrolled too far on mobile?

Tags: javascript, dom, mobile, scroll

I was curious if anything detectable happens in the DOM on a mobile browser when you are at the top or bottom of a page and try to scroll further, or if that is detectable through javascript.

Comment: I'd have to bet on "no" since it's a browser effect and not intended on a page, but hooking on this sounds pretty interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked on my Macbook pro laptop and yes, you can detect this.

I used jQuery to get the window's scrollTop() property and it would return a negative value when scrolled above the page.

My Code:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(
    console.log( $(this).scrollTop() );
)};
```

I would assume you can get the bottom scrolling by getting the viewport's height and add it with the scrollTop value.